# DatePicker Widget with a button which runs all the below cells from jupyter lab for that selected date

Tags: jupyter-notebook, datepicker, widget, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to create a DatePicker widget in Jupyter Lab with a button, when the user selects a date from the date picker and hits the button, all the below cells should start running for that date. I tried running below code and it is working as expected in the anaconda jupyter notebook but is not working in jupyter lab. Can you help me with the same?

```
from IPython.display import Javascript, display
import ipywidgets as widgets

fromDatePicker = widgets.DatePicker(description='fromdate')

ToDatePicker = widgets.DatePicker(description='fromdate')

def fromDate():
    return f"'{fromDatePicker.value}'"

def toDate():
    return f"'{ToDatePicker.value}'"

def run_all(ev):
    display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_cell_range(IPython.notebook.get_selected_index()+1, IPython.notebook.ncells())'))

    
button = widgets.Button(description="Run all")
button.on_click(run_all)
widgets.HBox([fromDatePicker, ToDatePicker, button])
```

after this to check whether it is working or not I'm printing the start date below :

```
print("start date is :", fromDate())
```

I expected that after clicking on the Run all button it should start executing the below cells but here I have to go to that cell and run it manually. Kindly please post your answers or suggestions below.

After using ipyab :

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipylab import JupyterFrontEnd
from IPython.display  import Javascript, display
app = JupyterFrontEnd()

fromDatePicker = widgets.DatePicker(
    description='From Date'
)
ToDatePicker = widgets.DatePicker(
    description='To Date'
)

button = widgets.Button(
    description='Execute',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='success',   
)

def fromDate():
    return f"'{fromDatePicker.value}'"

def toDate():
    return f"'{ToDatePicker.value}'"

def run_all(ev):
    app.commands.execute('notebook:run-all-below')

display(button)
    
button.on_click(run_all)  
widgets.HBox([fromDatePicker, ToDatePicker, button])
```

Above code is also running same as the first one

jupyter labextension list

JupyterLab v3.4.5
jupyterlab-execute-time v2.1.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_execute_time)
jupyterlab_pygments v0.2.2 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_pygments)
nbdime-jupyterlab v2.1.1 enabled OK
@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.1.1 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
@jupyterlab/geojson-extension v3.1.2 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab-geojson)
@jupyterlab/git v0.32.4 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab-git)

Disabled extensions:
@jupyterlab/extensionmanager-extension (all plugins)
@jupyterlab/running-extension (all plugins)

Comment: `IPython.notebook.execute_cell_range` is an old API which is no longer available (except for old notebook versions derived from old IPython notebook). You may be interested in using [ipylab](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab) with `notebook:run-all-cells` command.

Comment: Thanks  
krassowski
for your reply, i tried what you suggested but not working, i guess I'm doing some mistake, from ipylab i've imported JupyterFrontEnd and then defined app as app = JupyterFrontEnd() after that in run_all function im giving this ' app.commands.execute('notebook:run-all-below')' . Kindly correct me and give your solution with the same.

Comment: Sounds correct. Can you edit your question to include the `ipylab` code that you tried? Have you restarted/reloaded JupyterLab after installing ipylab? what is the output of `jupyter labextension list` when run in terminal?

Comment: Hi @krassowski please find the updated question. Thanks!